# Frustrating Android Autocorrects - OK, CE, SE

Tags: moto-x, auto-correct

My Android MotoX frustratingly auto corrects in the following ways...

```
some -> SE
come -> CE
ok -> OK
```

I've had a look through my `Settings > Languate & input > Personal dictionary` both `English (United States` and `For all languages` and have not found ANY entries for these.

I've tried creating an auto-correct entry so that 'ok' would be autocorrected to 'ok' (lowercase to lowercase) but that didn't work.

These terms are so generic that google searches are near useless.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've heard that `Clear Data` in Google Keyboard's App info would do it, but I have my doubts and would rather not lose all the legitimate auto-corrects I've stored.

Comment: What happens if you tap and hold on the CE box (at the top of the keyboard, not where you're typing)?

Comment: I'm actually having trouble duplicating the issue consistently where SE and CE are concerned. I've noticed that I'll type 'some' hit space and it auto-corrects to 'SE' for some unknown reason. But not always. Here's what I get with 'ok' though [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5Lq8I2j.jpg)

Comment: You could get another free keyboard app. The default app is quite limited.